# Get values from an Array into a variable [Azure Logic App]

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have an array variable "Names" with this values for example ["Unity","Block","PRD","Monit"] and want to get each of them value into a new variable.

The output desired would be something like:
Variable Group = Unity
Variabel Test = Block
(...)

As this is an array i thought a basic Names[0] would give me the first value and so on for 1,2,3,etc, but on a logic app I can't figure out how that works.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do know select value from an array have to specific the index,  just don't know how to use variable expression.

Use `variables('variable_name')` get the variable value and then add the parameter `[index]`  behind it to select the value you want. Just like the below picture shows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was it, perfect! Don't know why I didn't try that...seems so logical now. Thank you